# Were members of SA or SS paid - especially before 1933?

Tags: germany

I understand that the SA and SS already were pretty large organizations with tens of thousands of members, even before the NSDAP took over the rule in 1933.

Have the SA and SS been volunteer organizations or were SA and SS members some kind of employees or did they receive some other kind of compensation for their service? I have a hard time believing they all served just for their believes or their hope to gain some influence later on.

If they got paid, where did the money come from? Of course it's known that the NSDAP did have strong financial supporters, but paying for a paramilitary organization of that size would not have meant small money.

Are there any figures available?

Comment: What has your own research shown?

Comment: Nothing. This is why I am asking.

Comment: Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.

Comment: They want you to edit your question to tell us where else you looked.